# How to write query based on datagridview results?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hi I have a query which populates a datagridview which all works correctly. When the datagrid has been populated it has the following columns

UserID
UserName
UserDepot

I have a button which when pressed I would like to run another query based on the information in column UserID and whatever row is selected. I am having difficulty writing this query as I dont know what command I need to write in order to call this information

the datagrid is called dg_usersearch so I was expecting to use something like dg_usersearch.selectedvalue but selectedvalue isnt a member of datagridview does anyone know what command I should be using?

The query for filling the datagrid is as follows

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'creates a list of all incidents as per the search parameters
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim query As String = "select [userid],[username],[userdepot] from [tbluser]"
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyDATASOURCE")
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                connection.Open()
                adapter.Fill(dt)
                connection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    'checks to make sure query has results
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dgusersearch.DataSource = dt
        'if no results display the following message
    ElseIf dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox(Prompt:="No results for search request, please try again")
    End If
```

Comment: Can you show us how you fill it?

Comment: the DGV contains a collection of datagridviewrows - you want to use the *values* in one or more of the cells in the selected row.

Comment: @OneFineDay I have amended my code above to show the command used to fill the DG

Comment: @Plutonix so selectedrows.values? how would I tell it why column I want out of the row?

Comment: userid is col1 so it will be cells(0).  blah blah blah `= myDGV.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @Plutronix above,

```
myDGV.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```